# How to select an entire range in a sheet, and in another sheet keep pasting two columns from the range with a gap of 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the following code, but it is very specific:

```
Sub Macro 6 ()
    Windows("Projects_Europe2014 work.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B12:C16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("test1.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("Projects_Europe2014 work.xlsx").Activate
    Range("D12:E16").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("test1.xlsx").Activate
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("Projects_Europe2014 work.xlsx").Activate
    Range("F12:G16").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("test1.xlsx").Activate
    Range("J3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Code
```

Is there a way, i can keep increasing the range, without manually entering the cde?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Perhaps illustrate before and after data?

Answer (score 0):

Does the worksheet you are copying to contains preexisting data? If not you could just copy your whole range and then insert empty columns where need be - after every two consecutive columns involving data

You can try the below and see if it fits - you need to fill in your references first where commented. "RANGE_REF" is the starting point cell where pasting of the original range should occur

```
Sub pasteandinsert()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim r2 As Range

    'HERE
    Set r = Workbooks("Projects_Europe2014 work.xlsx").Worksheets("YOUR_WS").Range("YOUR_RANGE")
    r.Copy

    'HERE
    With Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("YOUR_WS2")
        .Activate
        'HERE
        .Range("RANGE_REF").Select
        .Paste
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'HERE
    Set r2 = Range("RANGE_REF").Resize(r.Rows.count, r.Columns.count)

    i = 3
    colcount = r2.Columns.count

    Do While i <= colcount
        r2.Columns(i).Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight
        r2.Columns(i).Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight
        i = i + 4
        colcount = colcount + 2
    Loop
End Sub
```